# Codeigniter - Load another View clicking Button

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

When clicking a button, show(load) another view of Controller with Ajax / Javascript. I tried to something but it doesn't work.

Javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#details").click(function(){
        $( "#result" ).load( "<?php echo base_url("orders/viewDetails"); ?>" );
    });
});
</script>
```

View:

```
<button id="details" href="#" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Show Order Items Details</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```

But It doesn't work. How can I do this correctly?

I put here my working code before I did it for "select input". How I change this code to button click? It may work for me.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function showInfo(str){

$.ajax({

type: "POST",

data: { cusId: str },

url: "<?=base_url('vehicles/getInfo');?>",

success: function(data) {

$('#divInfo').html(data);

}

});

}

</script>
```

View:

```
<select onChange="showInfo(this.value);" class="js-example-basic-single" name="docFileDocType" required="required">
```

Comment: `orders/viewDetails` is a controller and method or it's your view file?

Comment: orders/viewDetails is controller command.

Comment: It should load. Is there any JS error? If you access this controller command directly, it work?

Comment: I added $this->load->view('orders/view_result', $viewData); command already in controller. It must be work, I think.

Comment: OK, but try to access http://your-url/orders/viewDetails to see what's happening. Doesn't forget to check for JS errors.

Comment: base_url is working correctly. (base_url means site_url). It doesn't give any javascript error.

Comment: There is no js error when you click on "show order details"?

Comment: It doesn't give any js error when I clicked button.

Comment: OK, change your script to this: https://pastebin.com/Mgeq6VC9 and see what happens.

Comment: It gives alert Ok. There is no view.

Comment: But what is in the alert?

Comment: Alert gives : 200: OK.

Comment: I edited my question. Can we adapt this code to button click?

Comment: One last debug as it is now, try to alert "response" instead of status and statusText : https://pastebin.com/TChc46wE. It should work, I just made a test here.

Comment: It works, but how can I use this with PHP foreach function for getting information? It does not work for the others buttons. I listed customers on table, and table has info button for each customer. When clicked each customer info button, It must be listed info by customer. It could be worked by my old code in my edited question. But my code adapted for select input not for button. How can I do this js for button?

Comment: You could `<?php echo base_url("orders/viewDetails?id=xyz"); ?>` and load content of that id.

Comment: Can you show your answer completely?

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to use cookie to check witch view should be load. if user clicked on a btn, set a cookie and redirect to the same page. in header you check if cookie is set or not. if it is load new view. if not, load old one.

Comment: I want to use it like my question. Thanks for your suggestion.